# Why am I getting "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length" using pivot_longer?

Tags: r, tidyr

I am attempting to pivot redistricting data from the PL94171 package into long format and am having some trouble reshaping data.

I'd like pop_black, pop_asian ect to be reshaped into long format, where values are stored under population and the race is stored under a variable "race".

Here's the code I've tried, but I keep getting "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length".

```
library(PL94171)
pl_path = system.file("extdata/ri2018_2020Style.pl", package="PL94171")

(RI_tbl <- pl_tidy_shp("RI", pl_path))

GEOID    state county    vtd     pop pop_hisp pop_white pop_black pop_aian pop_asian pop_nhpi pop_other
   <chr>    <chr> <chr>     <chr> <int>    <int>     <int>     <int>    <int>     <int>    <int>     <int>
 1 4400700~ RI    Providen~ 4428~     0        0         0         0        0         0        0         0
 2 4400700~ RI    Providen~ 4428~     0        0         0         0        0         0        0         0
 3 4400700~ RI    Providen~ 4428~     0        0         0         0        0         0        0         0
 4 4400700~ RI    Providen~ 4428~    50        0        50         0        0         0        0         0

RI_tbl %>% select(starts_with("pop_")) %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(
    cols = starts_with("pop_"), 
    names_to = "race", 
    names_prefix = "pop_",
    values_to = "population",
    values_drop_na = TRUE,
  )
```

Comment: just remove the `select` line and it should work

Answer (score 0):

If we convert it to `tibble`, then the warning will be gone as the `sf` class attribute is creating the issue and then reconvert to back to `sf`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(sf)
RI_tbl %>%
    select(starts_with("pop_")) %>%
    as_tibble %>%
    tidyr::pivot_longer(
    cols = starts_with("pop_"), 
    names_to = "race", 
    names_prefix = "pop_",
    values_to = "population",
    values_drop_na = TRUE,
  ) %>%
 st_as_sf
```

-ouptut

```
Simple feature collection with 4552 features and 2 fields (with 112 geometries empty)
Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -71.43177 ymin: 41.77241 xmax: -71.36969 ymax: 41.82055
Geodetic CRS:  NAD83
# A tibble: 4,552 x 3
                                                                                  geometry race  population
                                                                        <MULTIPOLYGON [°]> <chr>      <int>
 1 (((-71.3975 41.80041, -71.39571 41.80164, -71.39563 41.80158, -71.39547 41.80169, -7... hisp           0
 2 (((-71.3975 41.80041, -71.39571 41.80164, -71.39563 41.80158, -71.39547 41.80169, -7... white          0
 3 (((-71.3975 41.80041, -71.39571 41.80164, -71.39563 41.80158, -71.39547 41.80169, -7... black          0
 4 (((-71.3975 41.80041, -71.39571 41.80164, -71.39563 41.80158, -71.39547 41.80169, -7... aian           0
 5 (((-71.3975 41.80041, -71.39571 41.80164, -71.39563 41.80158, -71.39547 41.80169, -7... asian          0
 6 (((-71.3975 41.80041, -71.39571 41.80164, -71.39563 41.80158, -71.39547 41.80169, -7... nhpi           0
 7 (((-71.3975 41.80041, -71.39571 41.80164, -71.39563 41.80158, -71.39547 41.80169, -7... other          0
 8 (((-71.3975 41.80041, -71.39571 41.80164, -71.39563 41.80158, -71.39547 41.80169, -7... two            0
 9 (((-71.39929 41.79935, -71.39922 41.79938, -71.39915 41.79941, -71.39895 41.79949, -... hisp           0
10 (((-71.39929 41.79935, -71.39922 41.79938, -71.39915 41.79941, -71.39895 41.79949, -... white          0
# … with 4,542 more rows
```

Answer (score -1):

I realize I may have not been clear about what I wanted, but I was able to run the following code to obtain the result I wanted.

The `sf` class attribute didn't seem to be a problem when I ran this code.

```
RI_tbl %>% select(!starts_with("vap")) %>% 
              pivot_longer(cols = pop_hisp:pop_two, names_to = "race", 
              values_to = "population",
              names_prefix = "pop_") %>% 
  select(race, population, GEOID:geometry)

 race  population GEOID   state county  vtd     pop area_land area_water                        geometry
   <chr>      <int> <chr>   <chr> <chr>   <chr> <int>     <dbl>      <dbl>              <MULTIPOLYGON [°]>
 1 hisp           0 440070~ RI    Provid~ 4428~     0         0     694774 (((-71.3975 41.80041, -71.3957~
 2 white          0 440070~ RI    Provid~ 4428~     0         0     694774 (((-71.3975 41.80041, -71.3957~
 3 black          0 440070~ RI    Provid~ 4428~     0         0     694774 (((-71.3975 41.80041, -71.3957~
 4 aian           0 440070~ RI    Provid~ 4428~     0         0     694774 (((-71.3975 41.80041, -71.3957~
 5 asian          0 440070~ RI    Provid~ 4428~     0         0     694774 (((-71.3975 41.80041, -71.3957~
 6 nhpi           0 440070~ RI    Provid~ 4428~     0         0     694774 (((-71.3975 41.80041, -71.3957~
```

Comment: Because you removed GEOID, etc from the pivot_longer columns